# Может ли кастомная прошивка быть причиной багов?

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток! Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: когда тестирую приложение на устройстве с родной прошивкой - всё норм, когда тестирую на устройстве с кастомной прошивкой - возникают баги, причём эти баги не воспроизводятся ни на устройстве с  родной прошивкой, ни на эмуляторе. Может ли причиной этих багов быть кастомная прошивка?

Comment: просто настораживает,что баги появляются именно на устройстве с кастомной прошивкой,а на устройствах с родной прошивкой их нет)

Comment: На андрофонах я часто меняю не только прошивки, но и ставлю кастомные ядра. Очень редко это влияет на программы из маркета, а если что-то случается, то это повод для багрепорта. Вообще ситуация совершенно стандартная: у разработчика "всё работает", а стоит только перенести на другую машину (и хорошо если это не демонстрация заказчику или хуже того - выставочный стенд) как всё рушится... И в подавляющем большинстве случаев ошибка ловится где-нибудь в самописном велосипеде :)

Comment: да да да, так все время и бывает по поводу демонстрации :DD

Comment: ну хорошо,а если такая ситуация:на устройстве с родной прошивкой багов нет,на устройстве с кастомной прошивкой А багов нет,а на устройстве с кастомной прошивкой С баг есть - тогда в чём причина?))Опять же,как мне кажется, многое ещё зависит от качества самой прошивки)

Comment: Причина в твоём коде. Предлагаешь всё бросить и взяться за его отладку?

Comment: видимо да)

Answer (score 4):

Причины багов - в программе :) А "непривычное" окружение только помогает им всплыть. Во всяком случае в 99% случаев именно так и бывает.

Answer (score 1):

Да, вполне может. В моей практике, на пример, Google Analytics на устройствах с кастомной прошивкой работает крайне редко(это связано с блокировкой гугловых хостов в прошивке).

Так же на неком старом девайсе LG была поставлена кастомная прошивка с андроидом 2.3.3, при том, что на девайсе всего 256 мб оперативной пямяти, что вызывало на нем Аут Оф Мемори при рендеринге некоторых изображений.

Кроме того, были проблемы с galaxy S и  S II, даже со стандартными прошивками.

А все потому, что у производителей смартов есть исходники Андроида, и они могут с ними делать "все, что захотят"